# How to save virtual listview immediately after it displays data?

Tags: delphi, tlistview

I want to save data in virtual listview immediately after it is filled. If I use Savedialog to save data, it works. If I call save procedure in ListviewOnData event, it prompts Error " Can not create file...". I reproduce my observation here.

```
procedure TForm6.savefileList(AListView: TListView; sFileName: string);

begin
F:= TFileStream.Create(sFileName, fmCreate or fmOpenRead);
...                                                       
...
F.free;

end;

Procedure Tform6.SavevirtualistinSaveDialog;// A buttonClick calls this procedure
begin
If SaveDialog1.execute then
savefilelist(listview1, savedialog1.FileName);; // It works and save data in sfilename.
..
end;

procedure TForm6.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin


with ld do begin     
...
...
// filling data in virtual list

end;
             // Right after filling data, I call Dosavelist procedure.
Dosavelist; //error line " Can not Create file", If I annotate this line
            // and call SavevirtualistinDialog in another buttonClick event, 
            //the data can be saved.

end;

Procedure Tform6.Dosavelist;
begin
savefilelist(listview1, extractfilepath(application.exename)+'list.tmp');
end;
```

I expect save the data in listview (virtual mode) right after it is filled. But it prompts errors.

How to solve it. Thank you in advance.

**New Edit:**

**I delete Dosavelist from listview1data event and put it in another function that tracks listview. It works. So it is solved. 
Thank you all for help.**

```
//My complete savefilelist para is:

savefilelist(listview1, extractfilepath(application.exename)+'list.tmp'); 

//In SavevirtualistinSaveDialog procedure, the complete save code line is: 

savefilelist(listview1, savedialog1.FileName);
```

Or Dosavelist procedure may not be called there? Where? How can I capture the moment when the virtual listview has just finished being filled? I do not know what event that is right after ListviewData event?

Thank you again.

Comment: I see you create a instance of TFileStream, the question is: do you also free it?! if not then you should, because the file is opened by the previous instance of the file stream.

Comment: In both cases you call savefileList with sFileName as a parameter.  I can't see where sFileName is declared, nor where you assign an actual filename to this variable?

Comment: @Jørn: In comments you can indicate code by surrounding it with \` characters. The \` is a "left single quote", and usually can be found in the vicinity of the tilde (~). Eg. `Stream.SaveToFile`.

Comment: @Marjan: Thank you.  I have seen the code formatting in comments, and I have tried with <code> and [code] markup. Now i know the `trick` :-)

Comment: Shouldn't `SavevirtualistinSaveDialog` be `If SaveDialog.execute then savefileList(AListView, SaveDialog.FileName);` (instead of `...sFileName);`)?

Comment: Thank you Jørn E. Angeltveit ,the complete savefilelist para is savefilelist(listview1, extractfilepath(application.exename)+'list.tmp');In SavevirtualistinSaveDialog procedure, the complete save code line is: savefilelist(listview1, savedialog1.FileName).

Comment: Are you sure that OnData event is the best place to save the content to file? That event is called a lot. Every time the ListView needs to repaint one item. Moving the mouse over items creates hundreds of calls to OnData. It also would be interesting to see how you populate the listview in the OnData event. For a virtual listview you set the caption of the Item parameter based on Item.Index. Changing Items.Count or do a ListView.Add will give you a error that is very appropriate for this site, "EStackOverflow".

Comment: Hi, Mikael. Nice to see you again.

Comment: Aha, it's you. Your user name is kind if hard to remember :).

Comment: Your edit shows that you're trying to write to the app directory. If your app is installed under "...\Program Files" this isn't allowed (depending on your Windows version). And it's never recommended. :-)

Comment: Thank you Ulrich, It is in D:\programs\... I just tested. If I move it to desktop, Dosavelist prompts the same error (...'can not create list.tmp,...another application is using it'), and again the SavevirtualistinSaveDialog works.

Comment: Another thought: A virtual listview shows data stored somewhere else (instead of explicitly added TListItems). Why don't you just save that data directly (without touching the listview)?

Comment: Thank you Ulrich, It has been the case for long. I like listview's vsreport style. What event might be right after virtual list has finished being filled? How to detect that it has been finished filling?

Comment: See my comment above: Why do you want to save **via the listview**? Why don't you just **directly** save the data? Then you wouldn't need to find any events.

Comment: If I put Dosavelist in an independent procedure, it works and saves data. I expect to know how to keep track of virtual listview status that has been finished filling.

Comment: @user482742 You appear to have a serious mis-understanding of virtual list views. The virtual list view just presents a *view* of the data which is owned and held somewhere else, by your code. You absolutely should not be saving the data in one of the list view events.

Comment: @David: That's what I was trying to say. You expressed it significantly more clearly. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds as if you don't specify an absolute file path. Then Windows relies on the current working directory when saving the file. The save dialog sets this directory, so everything works. In your ListviewOnData event, the cwd probably isn't set correctly.

Comment: Thank you Ulrich, In my savefilelist procedure, the complete savefilelist para is savefilelist(listview1, extractfilepath(application.exename)+'list.tmp');

Comment: AFAICS `extractfilepath(application.exename)+''` returns a directory, not a file path.

Comment: Thanks. And in SavevirtualistinSaveDialog procedure, the complete save code line is: savefilelist(listview1, savedialog1.FileName).